# Netbeans Clean and Build breaks Java Web Service URL

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans

When I add a web service to my java project, I can run the project and use all the web methods I have created.  However, after I clean and build the project, I get a console message that the service can't be found.  I do the clean and build so that I can deploy it to a web server, which has worked in the past.

I tried changing The JDK version from 8 to 7 and back, I checked the project properties, but I'm not sure what to look for there.  I also created a new web service with all the same web methods in it.  That works until I run a clean and build.  I also tried using Netbeans 8.1 instead of 8.2.

I must have changed something but I don't know what to look for.  I am using Tomcat 8 as my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  When I first tried to run a clean and build, I got the error that said that a file could not be deleted.  I deleted all files in the WEB-INF folder.  That included the web.xml that contained the directions for the app to find the web service.  Once I put that file back (thank you source control), it worked like I expected it to.